# Very basic line integrals (worked out)

Tags: calculus, integration

my problem is basically (among many others) my textbook sucks and the answers are frequently non nonsensical, sadly i haven't slept in a couple days so im not sure whos out to lunch.
gonna post the problem my steps to the answer and the answer in my book if you don't mind pointing out my mistake id really appreciate it.

(i) Find the arc length of the parametrized curve.

Question: $g(t)=(\frac{t^{3}}{3}-t,t^{2})$ where $t \in [0,2]$

Arc-length = $\int_{C}ds$

where $ds= \sqrt {(t^{2}-1)^{2}+(2t)^{2}}$

$ds= \sqrt {(t^{2}+1)^{2}}=t^{2}+1$

$\int^{2}_{0}t^{2}+1 =(\frac{t^{3}}{3}+t) |^{2}_{0}=\frac{14}{3}$ my book has the answer as 4.

(ii) Compute $\int_{C} \sqrt z ds$  where C is paramentrized by $g(t)=(2\cos t ,2\sin t , t^{2})$ where $t\in [0,2\pi ]$

$ds= \sqrt {(-2\sin t)^{2}+(2\cos t)^{2}+(2t)^{2}}$

$ds= \sqrt {4+4t^{2}}=2\sqrt {1+t^{2}}$

$\int^{2\pi}_{0} \sqrt{t^{2}}2\sqrt {1+t^{2}}dt$=$\int_{l} \sqrt {u}du$=$\frac  {2u^{3/2}}{3}$= $\frac {2}{3}((1+t^{2})^{\frac {3}{2}})|^{2\pi}_{0}$

=$\frac {2}{3}(1+4\pi^{2})^{\frac {3}{2}}$ my text books answer is $\frac {1}{3}(1+4\pi^{2})^{\frac {3}{2}}$ so at least were close this time O.o

(iii) Compute $\int_{C}$ **F** $\cdot$ d **x**

F(x,y)=$(x^{2}y,x^{3}y^{2}) $

C is the closed curve formed by portions of the line y=4 and $y=x^{2}$ orientated counterclockwise.

In this case i need to parametrize the function myself i decide to pick $x=t$ thus it follows $y=t^{2}$

so d **x** = $(1,2t)dt$ and F(t)=$(t^{2}t^{2},t^{3}t^{4}) $ thus

F(t) $\cdot$ d **x** =$(t^{4},t^{7})\cdot (1,2t)dt $ = $ t^{4}+2t^{8}$

$\int_{C}t^{4}+2t^{8}$=$(\frac {t^{5}}{5}+\frac {2t^{9}}{9})|_{C}$

Now here i actually run into quite a bit of problems what the hell C? 
Logically x is moving from -$2 \to 2$ and y is moving from $0\to4$.

But clearly as t goes from $0\to2$, I cover all of $y$ but somethings not right with x did i do my parametrization incorrectly?

Basically what i have is $\frac{9t^{5}+10t^{9}}{45}$
 when i evaluate t $\in [0,2]$ i get  $\frac{9(32)+10(512)}{45}$ =$\frac{5408}{45}$

my textbooks answer is $\frac{9856}{45}$  since 7|9856 with r=0 i have a very big problem if this is correct as $3^{n}2^{l}+5^{k}2^{m}$ where $(n,l,k,m) >0$ and are integers is never divisible by 7 which would mean my answer is clearly out to lunch.  being that my denominator is correct i am probably out by some constant in my parametrization.

I realize this is a rather large question but i think it will be fairly little to no effort involved to answer.

Cheers and thank you for the help!

Comment: why in (i) is $\frac{d}{dt} t^3 = t^2 -1$?

Comment: fixed now, parametrization wasn't written down correctly

Comment: Ok... in (i) i'm getting your sam result, in (iii) you did the integration only in the first half of curve!

Comment: im sorry can you please explain? i havent slept in a  couple  days you'll need to a bit more pointed for me to follow

Comment: If I understand well the question, you have to evalaute the work over the path which is A) $y=x^2, x\in (-2,2)$ plus B) $y=4 x\in (2,-2)... did you do B)?

Comment: We all see that you can do it! Simply go to sleep!

Comment: I oddly understand you but  as i sort of wrote above, but i have o idea which regio i even found the work over ( if any) i dont understand how i have to change the parametrization for this to work or what i can make t whenever i pick $t \in [-2,2]$ everything becomes zero but when i pick $t \in [0,2]$ i feel like im missing something

Comment: are you saying something like this?

x=t y=4 (1,0) $\cdot$ $4t^{2}\int^{2}_{-2}$ = $\frac{4t^{3}}{3}|^{2}_{-2}$ is part B? oddly this = $\frac{64}{3} = \frac {960}{45}$ and if you double my answer ie $2*(\frac {5408}{45})$ and subtract $\frac {960}{45}$ it equal's $\frac {9856}{45}$ i could perhaps easily believe my answer to part A is only half the work as i only let x varies from $0\to 2$  by would i be subtracting part b? one of those over-counting rules from my mes sup in part a?

Comment: In words, you have to evaluate the integral over the full path which is: from (0,0) to (2,4) along the parabola, from (2,4) to (-2,4) along the straight line, from (-2,4) to (0,0) along the parabola. However, I agree with Berci, get some sleep and everything will be easier! :D

Comment: 1) and 2) seem OK to me.

Comment: Should not the answer to (ii)  be
$\int_C  \ \sqrt{z} \ ds  \ = \ ( \frac{2}{3} \cdot [1 \ + \ t^2 ]^{3/2} ) |_0^{2 \pi}  \ = \  \frac{2}{3} \cdot [1 \ + \ 4\pi^2 ]^{3/2} \ - \ \frac{2}{3} \cdot 1 \ ? $  (It sure seems like the author or publisher didn't pay the student solvers much for your text to have such a high incidence of erroneous answers.)  I wasn't sure whether to bother entering an answer for (iii), since it seems it is mostly played out in the comments...